# Making a new UITableView cell's textField the firstResponder

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I currently have a table view with cells that contain a label and a `textfield`, I also have a + bar button item that adds new cells.

What I hope to accomplish is when the user presses the + button the new cell is created and the text field of this cell would automatically become first responder.

Below is my current code for creating the new entry:

```
func newNoteline() {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "NotebookContentEntity", in: context)
    
    let item = NotebookContentEntity(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
    
    item.notebookEntry = ""
    item.timeOfEntry = timeOutlet.text
    
    do {
        
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    loadNotelines()
}
```

I have thought of several ways of trying to solve this but without much luck of making them work including using a `.tag` on the text field as soon as it's made - using the text field delegate or using the `tableView` delegate method - `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView`.

I just can't figure out how to force the focus to a specific textfield within a cell without the user tapping the text field. Any thoughts?

Comment: you can call becomeFirstResponder of text field

Answer (score 1):

Calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder) should do what you are looking for.

When to call this function is up to you. for e.g. in below code at `cellForRowAt` I checked if the value is empty then make the current textfield first responder.

```
class Test: UIViewController{
    
    var myView: TestView{return view as! TestView}
    unowned var tableView: UITableView {return myView.tableView}
    unowned var button: UIButton {return myView.button}
    
    var list = [String]()
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = TestView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for i in 1...10{
            list.append("Test \(i)")
        }
        tableView.dataSource = self
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func didSelect(_ sender: UIButton){
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: list.count, section: 0)
        list.append("")
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}

extension Test: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        let value = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.textField.text = value
        if value.isEmpty{
            cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```